# How can i show all members of a group?

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I am pretty new to C# and SQL Server database.

I have created a database called groups. It looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to be able to list all the groups, one by one, and then see all the members in the group.

At the moment I am only able to make a view that lists all the students and then what group the student is in.

I want it so that is specify which students are in which group in the table: Student_rel_group, and then the Windows Form Application should show it like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me out here. The problem is the many-to-many relation. If the group had only one member, it was no problem, but i cant make it show all the members. Only one at a time... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. A simple one goes like this:

1. Create a DataSet with three DataTables
2. Load all groups in one DataTable and all Students in the other one and all relations in the third one.
3. Create DataSet Relations between the tables corresponding to the relations in your database.
4. Then you should be able to data bind the DataTables to your form control.

Note that this only makes sense if the number of rows in your database is not too large, say less than 10,000 perhaps 100,000.

Some links on how to do that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171915%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataset/dataset-relations.htm

Comment: Thank you, i'll look into it, and see if it will help me out

Comment: Im having a dataset looking like this now: http://billedeupload.dk/?v=BGDt7.png

But how do i get any further?

Comment: Look here to learn how you can display your data in the Windows Form: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx

Comment: Yeah, i know how to make the windows application, but i dont know how to make it show all the members of the group. I can only make it show the students, and then what group they are in. I want to see the groups and then all the members at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Are we missing something .
That's just

```
Select Student.* From Students 
inner join Student_rel_group on Student_rel_group.StudentId = Students.StudentId 
and Student_rel_group.GroupID = ???
```

Comment: Well we've got problems then, because if something that basic is skipping by you, communication is going to be 'erm difficult...

Comment: I know what the SQL sentence means, but you said we were missing something?
I did not create the SQL sentence myself, Visual Studio did in View...